# Is there any way to use encrypted password in pluginManagement section gradle

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

My plugin repository requires user and password credentials, I tried to use credentials plugin, but it's not possible to access credentials plugin in pluginManagement section in settings.gradle and there is no sence to use it only for build sections because I have to use unecrypted userName and password in pluginManagement section.

I tried to use credentials plugin in pluginManagenent section

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.